# What is the difference between HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and Server.HtmlEncode

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` and `Server.HTMLEncode`?

Comment: For .Net core See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352981/webutility-htmldecode-vs-httputilty-htmldecode

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at [Server.HtmlEncode vs HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/134990/server-htmlencode-vs-httputility-htmlencode) .

Basically, `Server.HtmlEncode` uses a specific instance of the `System.Web.HttpServerUtility` class that's inherited from the `Page` class. `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` is a static method, so you don't have to instantiate the `HttpUtility` class.

All else being equal, go with the static `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`.