# Convert html code to string .net

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, decode

I'm having problem converting html code to a string. Can someone explain how do I convert

```
Here&#8217;s What Happened Today: Wednesday
```

to

```
Here's What Happened Today: Wednesday
```

I've tried using `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`, but it still returns the string with the &#8217

Note I'm trying to do this within a WP8 app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on SO.

[WebUtility.HtmlDecode vs HttpUtilty.HtmlDecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352981/webutility-htmldecode-vs-httputilty-htmldecode)

Seems to output different values based on the function called.  I would use **HttpUtility.HtmlDecode** instead since it's matching your the behavior that you want.

Comment: Bang on!! I didn't think http utility was available in wp8 but it is and it worked. Kind of poor from MS that the behaviour is different for the 2 as you would think that both would behave the same way. Wasted so much time on this, thinking I was doing something wrong! Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah I read the comment on that page seems a lot of people wasted a lot of time figuring it out.