# How to replace a character in C# string ignoring other characters?

Tags: c#

Consider that I have a following string:

```
string s = "hello a & b, &lt;hello world &gt;"
```

I want to replace `"&"` (b/w a and b) with `"&amp;"`

So, if I use

```
s.replace("&", "&amp;");
```

It will also replace "&" associated with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Is there any way I can replace only "&" between a and b?

Comment: As with all cases of string encodings, you ought to know in what format the original string is to implement a correct function. For instance, is the original string intended to be a "raw string" or a "string with HTML entities"? The [answer by Karan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63554951/603003) is only correct for the latter.

Comment: Karan's answer is a good one, but you should try to avoid this situation in the first place. How did you come to have a string that's a mix of html entities and unencoded & symbols? Could you have encoded the & before combining with the &lt;?

Comment: @ComFreek: As with many of the encoding questions here on SO, I think the answer to your question is: "The original string is an arbitrary mix on HTML-encoded and non-HTML-encoded strings created by someone who doesn't know what they are doing, and I have been tasked to 'fix it' in a later stage. I know that this is impossible in the general case, so please provide a hack that works for most cases and I'll pray that the edge case which finally subtly breaks it only comes around after I have left the company".

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can rather use [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode) & [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode) like below.

First decode your string to get normal string and then encode it again which will give you expected string.

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("hello a & b, &lt;hello world &gt;"));
```

- `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("hello a & b, &lt;hello world &gt;")` will return `hello a & b, <hello world >`.
- `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("hello a & b, <hello world >")` will return `hello a &amp; b, &lt;hello world &gt;`

Comment: This is likely the most sane solution

Comment: I tried using WebUtility instead of HttpUtility, but it is not decoding &lt; and &gt; Are not these classes same?

Comment: It will work same, you can check it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/zU1qyZ. Also refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352981/webutility-htmldecode-vs-httputilty-htmldecode#:~:text=The%20difference%20is%20only%20intended,general%20purpose%20or%20client%20use.

Answer (score 6):

You could use regex, I suppose:

```
Regex.Replace("hello a & b, &lt;hello world &gt;", "&(?![a-z]{1,};)", "&amp;");
```

- **&**          match literal &
- **(?! )**      negative lookahead (assert that the following does not match)
- **[a-z]{1,};** any char a-z, one or more times, followed by a single ';'

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding spaces on both sides of the character in the search string:

```
s.replace(" & ", " &amp;");
```

Comment: what about `&` at the start or end of string?

Comment: What you have suggested can used for this specific string. In reality there might be very different situations as Ilya mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "hello a & b, &lt;hello world&gt;";
var sd =  s.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">");
var e = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sd);
WriteLine(e);
```

output:

> `hello a &amp; b, &lt;hello world&gt;`

Comment: what about `test &quot; test`?

Comment: @IłyaBursov, I've voted for https://stackoverflow.com/a/63554951/7052021 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think @afrischke's answer is good enough. But it may be a little too restrictive. In case you only want to ignore &lt and &gt, you can use the following.

```
Regex.Replace("hello a & b, &lt;hello world &gt;", "&(?!(lt|gt);)", "&amp;");
```

&(?!(lt|gt);) : Literal "&" which is not followed by "lt;" or "gt;".