# Any difference in using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() and Server.HtmlEncode()?

Tags: c#, html-encode

1. Is there any difference between `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` method and `Server.HtmlEncode()` method?
2. If not, what for one method duplicates another?

Comment: _Well_, since both method are exist, I think they are different ;)

Comment: See http://blog.diegocadenas.com/2008/03/serverhtmlencode-vs-httputilityhtmlenco.html

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you! Sorry for duplicate - my query for the search maschine wasn't so good :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374255/what-is-the-difference-between-httputility-htmlencode-and-server-htmlencode)

and may be this can help too

[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/134990/Server-HtmlEncode-vs-HttpUtility-HtmlEncode)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

1) They are the same.

2) It's a matter of convenience: Server.HtmlEncode() is readily availalble at runtime from a web page for example whereas HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() is a static method that can be used from anywhere.