# Server.HtmlEncode vs Encoder.HtmlEncode

Tags: c#, antixsslibrary

I have the below code in my MVC application.

```
 text = Server.HtmlEncode(text);
 text=Encoder.HtmlEncode(text);
```

what is the difference will do if I use AntiXSS library here?

I passed the value     `<script>alert("strek")</script>`

to the variable text it returns the same output for both the cases. Where it will make difference?

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374255/what-is-the-difference-between-httputility-htmlencode-and-server-htmlencode), `Server.HtmlEncode(text)` uses a instance of `System.Web.HttpServerUtility` while AntiXSS' [`Encoder.HtmlEncode(text)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) is static.

Comment: will it make any difference in the output?

Comment: I don't think so but I would advise using the static version.